# Field selected option giving invalid choices error

Tags: forms, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, backend, flask-wtforms

I a trying to select one product column which has option fetched from DB table. I want that user select that product and update details in front of it and that should be update in DB as well.

But on submitting form, it's throwing error:

```
{'Product': ['Not a valid choice']}
```

My validation is happening here:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
   
        sku=str(form.Product.data)
        SKU=Product.query.filter_by(Product=sku).update({Rate:f'form.Rate.data',Tax:f'form.Tax.data',Extra:f'form.Extra.data',})
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Data updated for {form.Product.data}!','success')
        return redirect(url_for('/'))
        print(form.errors)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        flash(f'Data not updated for {form.Product.data}','danger')
        
    return render_template('index.html',form=form, choices=choices)
```

HTML template look like this:

```
<select name="Product" id="Product">
    {% for choice in choices %}
    <OPTION name="Product" value="{{choice}}">
         {{choice}}
   </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I don't know what to do as I am new to Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Any help will be appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are generating list of options wrong. Try to save the list in a variable and then passing it to your form.

Answer (score 1):

After your form is instantiated, I think you need to set the value of choices as an attribute to your form, i.e.,

```
form.Product.choices = ['Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3']
```

I think this will resolve your 'Not a valid choice' error. Also, this way you don't need to pass `choices` as a separate argument to your html template. When you render your form you can simply do:

```
{{form.Product.label}}
{{form.Product}}
```